# HuggingFace Saving-Loading Model (Colab) to Make Predictions

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers

Using HuggingFace to train a transformer model to predict a target variable (e.g., movie ratings). I'm new to Python and this is likely a simple question, but I can’t figure out how to save a trained classifier model (via Colab) and then reload so to make target variable predictions on new data. As an example, I trained a model to predict imbd ratings with an example from the HuggingFace resources, shown below. I’ve tried a number of ways (save_model, save_pretrained) and either am struggling to save it at all or when loaded, can’t figure out what to call to get predictions. Any help would be incredibly appreciated on the steps that involve saving, loading, then creating new predicted scores based on the model on test data.

```
#example mainly from here: https://huggingface.co/transformers/training.html
!pip install transformers
!pip install datasets

from datasets import load_dataset
raw_datasets = load_dataset("imdb")

from transformers import AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")

def tokenize_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples["text"], max_length = 128, padding="max_length", truncation=True) 

tokenized_datasets = raw_datasets.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)

#choosing small datasets for example#
small_train_dataset = tokenized_datasets["train"].shuffle(seed=42).select(range(1000))
small_eval_dataset = tokenized_datasets["test"].shuffle(seed=42).select(range(500))

### TRAINING classification ###
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased", num_labels=2)

from transformers import TrainingArguments
from transformers import Trainer

training_args = TrainingArguments("test_trainer", evaluation_strategy="epoch", num_train_epochs=2, weight_decay=.0001, learning_rate=0.00001, per_device_train_batch_size=32) 

trainer = Trainer(model=model, args=training_args, train_dataset=small_train_dataset, eval_dataset=small_eval_dataset)
trainer.train()

y_test_predicted_original = model_loaded.predict(small_eval_dataset)

#### Saving ###
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
%cd /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/FOLDER

trainer.save_pretrained ("Trained model") #assumed this would save but did not
model.save_pretrained ("Trained model") #did save

### Loading Model and Creating Predicted Scores ###

#perhaps this....#
from transformers import BertConfig, BertModel
conf = BertConfig.from_pretrained("Trained model", num_labels=2)
model_loaded = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("Trained model", config=conf)

#or...#
model_loaded = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("Trained model", local_files_only=True)
model_loaded 

#with ultimate goal of getting predicted scores (not sure what to call here)...
y_test_predicted_loaded = model_loaded.predict(small_eval_dataset)
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the model

```
trainer.save_model("Trained model")
```

Load the model

```
model_loaded = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("Trained model")
```

Predict

```
trainer = Trainer(model = model_loaded)
test_results = trainer.predict(test_dataset)
```

Comment: I think that the `trainer.save_model("Trained model")` does not save the tokenizer in order to load it. Also, for the prediction you say `Trainer(model = model)` but where have you defined the model?

Comment: @GeorgePipis my bad.  I have fixed the answer